# EF Core : call stored procedure with DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I'm migrating my EF6 project to EF Core with .NET 7.

Tables were created correctly, but stored procedures and their results not. I followed this [guide](https://www.toptal.com/dot-net/entity-framework-core-stored-procedure).

I created a class of results `tsp_GetDocuments_Result` and a partial class of `DbContext`.

Here the code

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<tsp_GetDocuments_Result> tsp_GetDocuments_Result { get; set; }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<tsp_GetDocuments_Result>(entity =>
            entity.HasKey(e => e.IdDocumentHeader));
    }

    public IEnumerable<tsp_GetDocuments_Result> tsp_GetDocuments(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, int? warehouseFrom, int? warehouseTo, string documentType)
    {
        SqlParameter[] @params = new SqlParameter[] {
                 new SqlParameter() {
                            ParameterName = "@fromDate",
                            SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            Value = (object)toDate ?? DBNull.Value
                     },
                 new SqlParameter() {
                            ParameterName = "@toDate",
                            SqlDbType =  System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            Value = (object)toDate ?? DBNull.Value
                     },
                 new SqlParameter() {
                            ParameterName = "@warehouseFrom",
                            SqlDbType =  SqlDbType.Int,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            Value = (object)warehouseFrom ?? DBNull.Value
                     },
                 new SqlParameter() {
                            ParameterName = "@warehouseTo",
                            SqlDbType =  SqlDbType.Int,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            Value = (object)warehouseTo ?? DBNull.Value
                     },
                 new SqlParameter() {
                            ParameterName = "@documentType",
                            SqlDbType =  SqlDbType.VarChar,
                            Size = 20,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            Value = (object)documentType ?? DBNull.Value
                     }};
     
        var ent = this.tsp_GetDocuments_Result.
            FromSqlInterpolated<tsp_GetDocuments_Result>($"EXECUTE [dbo].[tsp_GetDocuments] '{@params[0]}',{@params[1]},{@params[2]},{@params[3]},{@params[4]}")
            .ToArray();

        return ent;
    }
}
```

Here is the SQL code of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tsp_GetDocuments]
    (@fromDate DATETIME,
     @toDate DATETIME,
     @warehouseFrom INT,
     @warehouseTo INT,
     @documentType VARCHAR(20))
AS
    SELECT 
        dh.IdDocumentHeader,
        ...
```

If I call the `EXEC` tsp from SQL Server Management Studio, I get the expected results

```
EXEC dbo.tsp_GetDocuments 
         @fromDate = '20230522 00:00', -- datetime
         @toDate = null,   -- datetime
         @warehouseFrom = null,                -- int
         @warehouseTo = null,                  -- int
         @documentType = null                 -- varchar(20)
```

If I call the stored procedure from my application, I get no results:

[image]

[image]

If I call the stored procedure from my application without setting the `fromDate` parameter, I get some results.

So I think the problem is the date, but I can't understand what I have to change.

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools to create the mappings for you

Comment: `'{@params[0]}'` why the apostrophes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FromSqlInterpolated you don't need SqlParameter objects.  Use SqlParameter objects with FromSqlRaw, eg

```
var ent = this.tsp_GetDocuments_Result
              .FromSqlRaw<tsp_GetDocuments_Result>("EXECUTE [dbo].[tsp_GetDocuments] @fromDate, @toDate, @warehouseFrom, @warehouseTo, @documentType", params)
              .ToArray();
```